# Отображение глиф-иконок на странице

Tags: html, css

На сайте есть два вида отображения элементов: в виде таблицы и сетки, которые меняют отображение в зависимости от клика по кнопке.

На странице имеется кнопка [image: картинка 1]. При переключении она меняется на такую (цвет не принципиален), где вместо глиф-иконки выводится [image: картинка 2].

Стили с текстом у обеих кнопок задаются через `:before {content:"";}`:

```
.archive .product-actions .compare:before {
    content: "Сравнить \f200";
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Плюс у второй кнопки есть стили:

```
.view-grid-center .product-frame .product-actions .compare:before {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

Почему так получается?

Comment: Надпись "Сравнить \f200" выводится каким шрифтом? Если кириллическим, то иконка не будет видна, если font awesome, то текст не будет виден.

Сделайте и вставьте рабочий пример в вопрос, тогда будет легче разобраться.

Comment: "Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой ("почему этот код не работает?") должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. Подробно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @SergeySnegirev  решение найдено - добавил вверху

Comment: @Вася, пожалуйста, оформите решение в качестве ответа - это необходимо для улучшения структуризации содержимого ресурса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение простое: для второй картинки задать `font-family: 'fontawesome';`